# Memcpy_p issues, how to resolve?

Tags: c++, arrays, avr

I'm puzzled by my own code :-) I'm trying to read data from PROGMEM. This works ok when I only have this array in PROGMEM. When adding an extra seperate array in PROGMEM it goes wrong. That is, when it's defined in a different piece of code and #included. When put together in 1 code it's fine. But I want these to arrays to live apart in different pieces of code.

I believe I have an error in the last function which I have include here (`callMenuItemParaName`).
It has to do with the way I'm reading out PROGMEM. I think it's best to use memcpy_P but cannot find any online explanation on how to use this exactly.

The code I have now works, but as long as I don't put another array in PROGMEM. (this routine is working correctly, with the memcpy_P function. But how do I implement memcpy_P in the function `callMenuItemParaName`?

Thanks for any advice you can give! (ofcourse pgmspace.h is included)

Working on AVR GCC, IDE is Eclipse, mcu = atmega644 @ 20MHz

```
unsigned char (*adresParaName);

const uint8_t TEXT0[] PROGMEM = "TEXT0";
const uint8_t paraNameAtk[] PROGMEM = "Atk  ";
const uint8_t paraNameDcy[] PROGMEM = "Dcy  ";
...
const uint8_t paraNameTru[] PROGMEM = "Tru  ";
const uint8_t paraNameLight[] PROGMEM = "Light";

typedef void (*pMenu)(void);

typedef struct
{
    void (*pointer2MenuNumber)(void);
    char  VALUE;
    const unsigned char *adresParaName;
} sel_item;

const sel_item menuNumber2ItemDbase[] PROGMEM=
{
    { itemA , 0x00 , TEXT0 },
    { itemB , 0x01 , paraNameAtk },
    { itemC , 0x02 , paraNameDcy },
        ...
    { itemM , 0x05 , paraNameTru },
    { itemN , 0x05 , paraNameLight }
};

//prototypes
void callMenuItem(const sel_item *item); 
void callMenuItemValue(const sel_item *item);
void callMenuItemParaName(const sel_item *item);

// *************************************************
// callMenu
// Description:
//
// *************************************************

void callMenuItem(const sel_item *item)
{
    pMenu function = (pMenu)pgm_read_word(&item->pointer2MenuNumber);
    function();
}

void callMenuItemValue(const sel_item *item)
{
    setCursor(1,4);
    char VAL = (char)pgm_read_byte(&item->VALUE);
    char2LCD('0'+VAL);
}

void callMenuItemParaName(const sel_item *item)
{
    char tempText[5];
    char *data = (char*)pgm_read_word(&item->adresParaName);

    strcpy_P (tempText, data);
    for (uint8_t x=0;x<5;x++)
        {
        char2LCD(tempText[x]);
        }
}
```

I've tried adding this:

```
char* pstr = 0;
memcpy_P (&pstr, data, sizeof(char*));
```

But no luck. (can't find a good tutorial on memcpy_P either, btw)

Comment: Where do you think `memcpy_P()` comes from?  It isn't a standard C function in the sense of ISO/IEC 9899:2011 — the current C standard. You could look up the SO question [`memcpy_P()` function in AVR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365462/memcpy-p-function-avr), but that doesn't explain what it means by 'program space'.  You may find [Program Space String Utilities](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/250a/docs/avr-libc-user-manual-1.2.5/group__avr__pgmspace.html) helpful.

Comment: Did not realise that it is AVR specific. I'll add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strings are 6 bytes long (remember the terminating 0), which means that you're overflowing `tempText` when you `strcpy_P` into it. Use `memcpy_P` instead.

```
memcpy_P(tempText, data, sizeof tempText);
```

The way you use `pgm_read_word` is just fine.

Comment: Right! That's it. I've tried your suggestion, which works out great! I was totally unaware of the terminating 0. Now, that would mean that if I would make tempText[6] instead of [5], strcpy_p would also work. Tested and works, but are there important things to take into account when choosing memcpy_P or strcpy_P?